# Babel v6: How/Can I write a plugin that adds a new syntax (ie a new operator)?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

> Note: I found this question on Babel issue tracker (https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T2653) and it was rejected, but AFAIK its author did not asked it here.

I've checked Babel plugins like [packages/babel-plugin-syntax-do-expressions](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-syntax-do-expressions) and it seemed that these ES6+ new syntax/operators weren't actually defined in the plugin at all but being [implemented in Babylon](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/89d9db86488e61b7a5a3e00157d9544df424743e/packages/babylon/src/parser/expression.js#L411-L422) and simply being [toggled on](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/88ab37ecb41db07dc0f81cb4c27587c1a3a1c489/packages/babel-plugin-syntax-do-expressions/src/index.js#L4) by these plugins.

Leaving the claim in the [newest blog post](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/29/6.0.0/) that "Developers have built everything from debugging tools [...] to experimental new syntaxes [...] to enforce complex rules on their codebases" dubious - actually, I've searched the entire plugin ecosystem but found no plugin being able to offer new operators/syntax, and only exactly one plugin that's able to offer operator overloading for a few existing operators.

So, is it really true that with Babel v6 we'll be able to see new operators/syntax being defined in the userland, and how?

This is also my opportunity to thank the whole Babel team for the good work!

PS: I started searching how to extend Babylon parser syntax in order to implement a plugin which would implement "pattern matching" like in [Julia methods](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/methods/).

Comment: I have the same question, but I did manage to get a syntax plugin working without hacking any core files. It's a plugin for [DCI](http://fulloo.info/) and it's still in development but the [TransferMoney.js](https://github.com/mbrowne/babel-dci/blob/master/babel-plugin-transform-dci/examples/TransferMoney/TransferMoney.js) example file does parse correctly: https://github.com/mbrowne/babel-dci. The way I've imported the `babylon` library seems fragile though; hopefully there's a better/more official way to do it. I'll probably follow up with the Slack community...

Comment: Note that in order for it to work, you have to get the instance of `babylon` used by the currently-loaded parser...so you can't just do `npm install babylon` inside the plugin folder - that would load a separate copy of babylon. That's why I imported it as `babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/...`.

Comment: Note that the Babel team has not made the parser plugin API public yet, so all of this is subject to change anyway. I'm sure there will be a better way to write parser plugins in the future.

Comment: I looked for the same thing and couldn't find it either, so agree that people have been overstating Babel's flexibility. I'm trying to fix the issue, and am currently working on a library that lets you easily define your own dialects of JavaScript, and compile their source to Babel ASTs. It still being worked on, but will be out soon.

Answer (score 5):

As of Babel v6.18.0, `parserOpts` option has been added that allows to pass configuration to the parser, i.e. to [Babylon](https://github.com/babel/babylon).

Babylon accepts options [`plugins`](https://github.com/babel/babylon/blob/v6.15.0/src/options.js#L10), which can be used to specify a list of plugin names to enable. At the time of this writing, you can only refer to one of the [plugins built into Babylon](https://github.com/babel/babylon/tree/v6.15.0#plugins).

There have been multiple suggestions to allow external plugins, e.g.

- https://github.com/babel/babylon/pull/5
- https://github.com/babel/babylon/pull/11
- https://github.com/babel/babylon/issues/22

The consensus is ~

> We've been against the idea of allowing external extensions to Babylon in the past. It would be much more difficult to support custom parsing than it is to support custom transformations. Babel already has a lot it has to support, so we haven't wanted to open this up.

– https://github.com/babel/babylon/pull/5#issuecomment-195801336

To enable custom parsing, you need to:

- fork Babel and Babylon; or
- use https://github.com/sweet-js/sweet.js

Answer (score 1):

A while back, I built a thin wrapper around Babel v6 to enable "advanced" plugins (i.e. plugins that add new syntax):

https://github.com/lukehorvat/babby

Babby is purely an experiment, and not something you should really use. But it does show you the minimum changes that would need to be made to Babel/Babylon for it to support the kinds of plugins that the OP is talking about.

Answer (score 0):

The [babel-plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator) plug-in adds a new operator (`**`).  It seems like you should be able to start with their code (it's pretty simple) to build your own, different, operator.

Comment: `**` is not a new operator. It is a valid [`BinaryExpression`](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-types#binaryexpression) type. It is supported by Babylon.

Comment: The "exponentiation" operator was introduced in ES7.  From the MDN: "This is an experimental technology, part of the ECMAScript 2016 (ES7) proposal." (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation_(**)).  Of course, what Babel does is Babel's business, but why would that plugin even exist if `**` was supported in base Babel?

Comment: Sorry, my phrasing is wrong. Regarding "not a new operator", I meant – it is an operator that Babylon supports, and not a new operator that a plugin adds. "but why", because Babylon is a parser and Babel is a transpiler. Babel plugins are transpilers.

Answer (score 0):

In my simple understanding of how babel or in general compilers work, it's not possible to have a babel plugin to "add new syntax".

In order to do that, you'd have to fork babel parser and add your new syntax there. Then you can have your custom plugin to use your forked, custom parser.